# Informatica map hundreds of columns to a single column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I would like to know the best approach or suggestions to map hundreds of columns to one column with informatica. I have tried with a union which produces the correct results but there are hundreds more columns to transpose to the single column and my system is now freezing up.

Comment: You can use Normalizer, I guess.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment the normalizer took care of it.